# Как вывести масив в два столбца

Tags: java

У меня есть два массива значений, как их вывести в два столбца?

То есть `данные1 || данные2`

```
for (Element line : allLines) {
    //String currency = line.select("").text();
    String bidPrice = line.select("td[data-rate-type=bid]").text();
    String prodaja = line.select("td[data-rate-type=ask]").text();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] += prodaja + "\n";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
       b[j] += bidPrice + "\n";
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

}

for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    System.out.print(b[j]);
}
```

Comment: А количество элементов в двух массивах одинаково? Если "да", то можно просто вывести в одном цикле...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] c = new string[a.length];
for (Element line : allLines) {
    //String currency = line.select("").text();
    String bidPrice = line.select("td[data-rate-type=bid]").text();
    String prodaja = line.select("td[data-rate-type=ask]").text();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      if (c[i] == null)
        c[i] = "";
      c[i] += prodaja + "   |   " + bidPrice + "\n";
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    System.out.print(c[i]);
}
```

Comment: Во первых, нужен стринг билдер для конкатинации ( так как это все не оптимизировано), во вторых, зачем все так усложнять?

Answer (score 1):

Если кол-во элементов в массивах одинаковое, то:

```
for (int i = 0;i<a.length.;i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i] + "   |   " + b[i]);
}
```

Comment: Одинаковое, но оно не выводит так, у меня два одновымерних масива, и так как вы написали почемуто не получается

Comment: @CR7 значит вы что-то не так делаете. ответ вам дали правильный

Comment: @Санаев ну у меня выводятся в столбец дальше,вот посмотрите на код и скажите где ошибка

Comment: @CR7 а что у вас выводится? что за объект такой Element?

Comment: @Санаев выводятся два массива в один столбец

Comment: @CR7 ваш проект есть на гите?

Comment: @Санаев на гите нету, Element это библиотека jsoup, я паршу сайт, и через Element  я заходжу в строку, и он забирает указаные данные

Comment: @Санаев ну так что что нибудь поможете?

Comment: @CR7 киньте абсолютно полный код